# Free functor $\mathsf{sSet} \to \mathsf{sGrp}$ on homotopy groups

Tags: reference-request, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

The free functor $\mathsf{sSet} \to \mathsf{sAb}$ corresponds to the Hurewicz map on homotopy groups.

What about the free functor $\mathsf{sSet} \to \mathsf{sGrp}$? What effect does it have on homotopy groups? It has to abelianize $\pi_1$, since simplicial groups have all abelian homotopy groups, by an Eckmann-Hilton argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $K$ is a simplicial set, then the free simplicial group on $K$ is naturally weak equivalent to $\Omega\Sigma K_+$ (with the inclusion of $K$ into the free simplicial group corresponding to the natural inclusion $K\to K_+\to \Omega\Sigma K_+$).  More generally, if $K$ is a pointed simplicial set and you take the pointed free simplicial group on $K$ (where "pointed free" means that the basepoint of $K$ becomes the identity in the group), this is naturally weak equivalent to $\Omega\Sigma K$ (again, in a way compatible with the canonical maps from $K$).  See, for instance, Corollary V.6.17 in Goerss and Jardine's *Simplicial Homotopy Theory*.  The induced map on homotopy groups can thus be identified with the suspension map $\pi_n(K)\to\pi_{n+1}(\Sigma K)$.  Of course, unlike the case of the Hurewicz map, the codomain $\pi_{n+1}(\Sigma K)$ is typically not particularly easy to compute.

Morally, what's going on is that a group structure on a pointed space is equivalent (up to homotopy) to a loopspace structure (i.e., another space that it is the loopspace of).  So you should expect the free group on a space $K$ to be the initial loopspace that $K$ maps into.  A map $K\to \Omega X$ is the same as a map $\Sigma K\to X$, and the initial such $X$ is just $\Sigma K$, so the initial loopspace $K$ maps into is $\Omega\Sigma K$.

Comment: What maps on homotopy groups does the abelianization functor $\mathsf{sGrp} \to \mathsf{sAb}$ correspond to?

Comment: Hmmm, good question.  I think that the abelianization functor does not preserve weak equivalences, so if you want a good answer you'll need to take a derived version of it (before abelianizing, take a cofibrant replacement of your simplicial group).  I would guess that if $G$ is a simplicial group and $A$ is its derived abelianization, then $\pi_n(A)\cong H_{n+1}(BG)$, with the map $\pi_n(G)\to H_{n+1}(BG)$ being the composition of the isomorphism $\pi_n(G)\cong \pi_{n+1}(BG)$ and the Hurewicz map for $BG$.  But I don't know a reference or proof off the top of my head.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the precise version of your statement that a simplicial group structure on a pointed simplicial set is equivalent to a loopspace structure? Thanks as always!

Comment: I'm not sure what the best way to formulate that is, but one formulation is that the model category of simplicial groups is Quillen equivalent to the model category of reduced simplicial sets (simplicial sets with a single $0$-simplex), with the equivalence taking a reduced simplicial set to a simplicial group that is weak equivalent to its loopspace.  This is Proposition V.6.3 in Goerss-Jardine.

Comment: (Note that a reduced simplicial set is in particular connected, and this is important since $\Omega X$ only depends on the basepoint component of $X$ so the delooping of a group can only be uniquely determined if you require it to be connnected.  So what I said isn't quite correct: a group structure on $X$ is equivalent (in a homotopical sense) to a _connected_ pointed space $Y$ which $X$ is the loopspace of.)